# how to link to a specific tab by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button, tabs, external

I have 2 html pages.
Page 1 has 3 tabs with contents. When I click on tab 3, there is a link that takes me to a new page. On the new page there is a "return" button, and when I click on the button it takes me back to the previous page, however, with tab #1 being active. Is there a way to make it when I click on the "return" button, tab #3 being active instead of tab#1.

```
enter code here
    //page 1:
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabSet" role="tablist" id="myTab">
   <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="up">tab3</a>  </li>
```

```
  //page 2:
  enter code here <input type="button" id="`Button" name="returnButton" value="Return to Report" onclick="returnToPrevious()" class="btn btn-primary" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function returnToPrevious()
{
    parent.history.back();
    return false;
}
 </script>
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that playing with the url query string: if the url contains a certain parameter, then active the third tab.

Assuming that the first page is called `first-page.html`, you can change the javascript code of the second page in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function returnToPrevious()
{
    location.href = "first-page.html?back=yes";
    return false;
}

</script>
```

And in first page you can active the first or the third table evaluating if the `back=yes` part is present or not in the url:

```
<!-- Notice that the class "active" is not present, because it will be managed in the javascript -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabSet" role="tablist" id="myTab">
   <li><a href="#tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="up">tab3</a></li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">

// Function that takes a param value from the query string of the url
// source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/
function getQueryStringVariable(variable)
{
   var queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = queryString.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
       var pair = vars[i].split("=");
       if(pair[0] == variable){
            return pair[1];
        }
   }
   return false;
}


// Checks if the "back=yes" part in the url is present
var back = getQueryStringVariable("back");
if (back === "yes")
{
    $("a[href=#tab-3]").addClass("active");
}
else
{
    $("a[href=#tab-1]").addClass("active");
}

</script>
```